# Firebase. How to detect when device network connection is restored?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, connectivity

Our team is faced with a delimma where we need to at app-run time, detect (and then make an action) when a mobile device connection is made with Firebase. Our app needs to store value locally to SQL Lite when offline, and then push these cached values back up to the realtime-database in Firebase when the connection is restored. Presently this re-connection to Firebase is only happening with our App is shutdown and restarted.

It seems that (at least with typescript) everything is governed by the `app.component.ts` file.  Is there a way to force the '.info/connected' to be true when the device network connection comes back .. and do this while our app is still running (memory on the mobile)?

Comment: You're supposed to listen to the value of `.info/connected` to determine when connection is restored.  Is that not working for you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: No this is not working as it does not turn on when you go back from airplane mode to online again

Comment: How long are you waiting?  It will not necessarily reconnect immediately.  It might take some time.  (You cannot force it, you will have to wait.)

Comment: Same as Doug here: `info/connected` is supported to switch to true once the connection to the back-end is restored. If that's not working for you, edit your question to include: 1) the minimum code to show the test, 2) reasonable debug logging to show what's going on. I also recommend [turning on debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#enable-logging), since that makes the Firebase client log its efforts to reconnect.

Comment: I should add (so that it is clear), we are connecting to the realtime-database, not the cloud-firestore